# Mostrar mensaje "no hay resultados" cuando no hay registros en la Db o cuando la busqueda no arroja coincidencias

Tags: sql, ajax, bootstrap

Buen dia, deseo colocar un simple mensaje, que al momento de yo hacer una busqueda, o no se encuentre ningun registro en la Db mueste un mensaje avisando que no hay registros y que no hay coincidencias al momento de la busqueda.

dos mensajes alert difetentes

mi codigo >

```html
 if($action == 'ajax'){
  // "escape", además eliminando todo lo que podría ser código (html / javascript-)
         $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
   $aColumns = array('fecha'); // Columnas de busqueda
   $sTable = "asistencia";
   $aTable = "personal";

   $sWhere = "";
   $FechaWhere = "";

  $order=" order by fecha desc";

  if ( $_GET['fecha'] != "" )
  {
   $FechaWhere = "WHERE fecha ='".$_GET['fecha']."' ";

  //MENSAJE
   echo '<i class="fas fa-filter"></i> Filtrando por fecha: ';
   echo $_GET['fecha'];
  }

  include 'pagination.php'; // incluir archivo de paginación
  // variables de paginación
  $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
  $per_page = 10; // ¿Cuántos items quieres mostrar?
  $adjacents  = 4; // Brecha entre páginas después del número de adyacentes.
  $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
  // Cuenta el número total de filas en la tabla */
  // $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable AS asis INNER JOIN $aTable AS per ON asis.id_personal = per.cedula $sWhere $FechaWhere $order");
  $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable $FechaWhere");
  $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
  $numrows = $row['numrows'];

  $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
  $reload = './asistencias.php';

  // consulta principal para recuperar los datos
  $sql="SELECT  *  FROM  $sTable AS asis INNER JOIN $aTable AS per ON asis.id_personal = per.id_personal $FechaWhere order by fecha desc LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
  // echo $sql;
  $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  // los datos obtenidos
  if ($numrows>0){

   ?>
   <div class="table">
     <table id="hola" class="table table-responsive-ml table-striped table-hover">
    <tr  class="table-primary">
     <th> Fecha</th>
     <th> Cédula/ID</th>
     <th> Empleado</th>
     <th> Asistencia</th>
     <th></th>
     <th class="text-right">Acciones</th>

    </tr>
    <?php
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $id_asistencia=$row['id_asistencia'];
      $id_personal=$row['id_personal'];
      $justificativo=$row['justificativo'];
      $cod_asistencia=$row['cod_asistencia'];
      $fecha= date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['fecha']));

      $nombre=$row['nombre_personal'];
      $apellido=$row['apellido_personal'];
      $cedula=$row['cedula'];

     ?>
     <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $fecha;?></td>
      <td>V<?php echo $cedula; ?></td>
      <td>
      <?php echo $nombre; echo ' '; echo $apellido; ?>
      </td>
      <td><?php if($cod_asistencia === '1'): ?>
        <span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> <?php echo "Asistio"; ?></span>
         <?php else: ?>
        <span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> <?php echo "No Asistio"; ?></span>
         <?php endif;?></td>
      <td>
      <!-- Boton Justificativo solo saldra si el empleado no Asistio -->
      <?php if($row['cod_asistencia'] === '2'): ?>
        <span class="badge badge-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $justificativo; ?>" data-placement="bottom"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i> <a href="#" data-id_personal='<?php echo $id_personal;?>' data-justificativo='<?php echo $cod_asistencia?>' data-id='<?php echo $id_asistencia;?>' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" style="color:black;">Justificativo</a></span>
       <?php else:?>
       <span class="badge badge-success"></span>
      <?php endif;?>
       <!-- Fin justificativo -->
      </td>
     <td style="text-align: right">
     <!-- Inicio Botones -->
     <?php  if($_SESSION["privilegio"] === '1'): // boton eliminar dice: si es priviegio 1 (admin) le permitira eliminar, else, boton desactivado.?>
      <div class="row" style="text-align: right">
       <div class="col-5"><a href="#" title='Editar Asistencia' data-fecha='<?php echo $fecha;?>' data-id_personal='<?php echo $id_personal;?>' data-asistencia='<?php echo $cod_asistencia?>' data-id='<?php echo $id_asistencia;?>' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" class="badge badge-secondary"><!-- Icono  --><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><!-- Icono  --></a></div>
       <div class="col-5"><a href="#" title='Borrar Asistencia' onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id_asistencia; ?>')" class="badge badge-dark"><!-- Icono  --><i class="fas fa-trash"></i><!-- Icono  --></a></div>
       </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <span class="badge badge-danger"><div class="col"><a title='Solo administradores'><!-- Icono  --><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><!-- Icono  --></a></div></span>
          </span>
     <?php endif;?>
     <!-- Fin botones -->
    </div>
     </td>

     </tr>
     <?php
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
     <td colspan=8><span class="pull-right">
     <?php
      echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
     ?></span></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
</div>
   <?php
  }
 }
?>
```

Tengo echo esto, pero, he colocado en varias zonas el mensaje else error para cuando no se encuentran registros y no me funciona, necesito ayuda :( mi problema creo que es de sintaxis mas que todo. agrego que el buscador funciona bien, pero cuando no hay registros no me muestra nada y se ve algo feo xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se encuentra en cuando obtienes los resultados:

```
$numrows = $row['numrows'];
$total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
```

Si el resultado no te devuelve nada es 0 o si tu consulta está incorrecta te regresa un null, entonces antes de dividir, deberías validar que traes, si es un 0 o un null no deberías dividir. Compara antes

```
if( $numrows != 0 && $numrows != null){
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
}
```

Lo mismo deberías aplicar en el ciclo que te permite hacer tu paginado.

Saludos.